# Execute AJAX call in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the PHP framework "KissMVC", at kissmvc.com.

But there aren't any examples of how to execute a AJAX call in the 'view'-page.
Does anyone know how to do that?

This is the code a placed in the view:

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo myUrl(CONTROLLER_PATH); ?>' + "register",
    data:
    {
       user_name: reg_username,

    }
});
```

Comment: Well, you have a javascript that is loaded together with your view. That implements the ajax call and executes it whenever convenient: after loading the page or as the reaction on some event.

Comment: So that is what I did, but then it should redirect to a PHP page, and this isn't working for a unkown reason. This is the code a placed in the view. http://pastebin.com/03sAieS7

Comment: Please add the code to your question. There is an `edit` button below the question.

Comment: how is that php code supposed to run? Also, letting the client dictate php code is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Solved the problem, had to change something in htacess for url rewriting, thanks guys!